# size of exported objects with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I used pg_dump with the directory format (-d) to export a database containing more than a hundred tables.
By comparing the .dat file for a table with its size in the database, I observed that the .dat file is twice larger.
How to explain this difference?

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 postgres postgres 39G May 12 13:36 5247.dat

5247; 0 15391537 TABLE DATA schemaname mytable owner

database=# select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('mytable'));
┌────────────────┐
│ pg_size_pretty │
├────────────────┤
│ 20 GB          │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Maybe many long strings that can efficiently be compressed inside the database. Or a lot of numbers. `2147483645` takes only four bytes in the database, but 10 when exported to a text file.

Comment: What was the complete `pg_dump` command given?

Comment: I'm thinking you turned off compression for the dump. When I do: `pg_dump -Fd -d production -U postgres -p 5442 -f pg/` I get `*.dat.gz` files in the `pg/` directory.

Comment: options used with pg_dump:  -F d -j 8 -Z 0 -C -f I put compression value to 0 that for performance reason. I come back to your first comment, the table has indeed a jsonb field with extended storage.

Comment: Yeah, so you have to decide which is more important speed or storage? See [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) for more on the compression in the database.